# mvc dropdownlist selected item issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, selecteditem, html.dropdownlistfor

Good evening everybody I have a question about dropdown selected item. I have a data on my database and I am selecting and showing them in my grid. However when I want them to edit the dropdown field does not come to me as selected. I tried to do it like this here are my codes but it didnt work. Is there anything that I missed here or should I need to change this code?

```
public ActionResult OrderEdit(int id)
    {
        Repository<Order> _ro = new Repository<Order>();
        Order _order = _ro.Find(o => o.id == id);

        int _selectedId=_order.customerProductTypeId;

        //IEnumerable<CustomerProductType> _departmentList = _rd.All();
        //var _department = _departmentList.Where(d => d.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        Repository<Customer> _rc = new Repository<Customer>();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _customerSelectListItem = _rc.All().AsEnumerable().Select(s =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = s.name,
                Value = s.id.ToString(),
                Selected=this.MySelected(s.id,1)
            });


        ViewData["ddCust"] = _customerSelectListItem;

        Repository<CustomerProductType> _rcp = new Repository<CustomerProductType>();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _customerProductTypeSelectListItem = _rcp.All().AsEnumerable().Select(s =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = s.name,
                Value = s.id.ToString(), 
                Selected=this.MySelected(s.id,_selectedId)
            });



        ViewData["ddDepartment"] = _customerProductTypeSelectListItem;

        //IEnumerable<MyCustomerProductType> _customerProductType = _rd.All().Select(s=> new MyCustomerProductType {id = s.id, customerName=s.customer.name,productTypeName = s.productType.name,name=s.name});
        //var _department = _customerProductType.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(_order);
    }

    private bool MySelected(int _id, int _selected)
    {
        bool _b = false;

        if (_id.Equals(_selected))
            _b=true;

        return _b;
    }
```

and my view is like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditOrder","Order",FormMethod.Post)) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Order</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.code)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.code)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.code)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.customerProductType.customerId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.customerId)*@
        @Html.DropDownList("ddCust",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddCust"],"secim yapınız", new { @class = "span6 chosen" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customerProductType.customerId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.customerProductTypeId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.customerProductTypeId)*@
        @*@Html.DropDownList("ddDepartment",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddDepartment"],"secim yapınız", new { @class = "span6 chosen" })*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customerProductTypeId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.price)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.orderDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.orderDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.orderDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.state)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.state)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.customerProductTypeId,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddCust"],"secim yapınız", new { @class = "span6 chosen" })
```

customerProductTypeId is where you will get and set the values of dropdown